# Can't get fractal image to work

Tags: python, image

So I'm working on a homework assignment regarding using image objects in python. I'm using python 3.4.1 for this assignment. I feel like I have everything done, but it doesn't want to work correctly. Basically, I'm trying to get it to look like the picture that I've attached, but it only shows as 1 red line across, and 1 red line top to bottom on a white background. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

The attached image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPRIF.jpg

```
import cImage as image

width = 500
height = 500

img = image.EmptyImage(width, height)
win = image.ImageWin("Exercise 3", width, height)
img.draw(win)

for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        p = img.getPixel(col, row)

        if row == 0 or col == 0:
            p = image.Pixel(255, 0, 0)
        else:
            Sum = 0
            temppixel = img.getPixel(col-1, row)
            if temppixel.getRed() == 255:
                Sum = Sum + 1
            elif temppixel.getBlue() == 255:
                Sum = Sum + 2      

            temppixel = img.getPixel(col-1, row-1)
            if temppixel.getRed() == 255:
                Sum = Sum + 1
            elif temppixel.getBlue() == 255:
                Sum = Sum + 2  

            temppixel = img.getPixel(col, row-1)
            if temppixel.getRed() == 255:
                Sum = Sum + 1
            elif temppixel.getBlue() == 255:
                Sum = Sum + 2                

            if Sum % 3 == 1:
                p = image.Pixel(255, 0, 0)
            elif Sum % 3 == 2:
                p = image.Pixel(0, 0, 255)
            else:
                p = image.Pixel(255, 255, 255)

        img.setPixel(col, row, p)

    img.draw(win)        

img.draw(win)

# uncomment this to save the image as a file
#img.saveTk("gradient.gif")

win.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code does exactly what you have written it to do. Let's name the three first `if ... elif` condition1, 2 and 3 :

1. The first pixel is set to red
2. Then we progress through the first line, so `row = 0` which means condition 2 and 3 are using invalid coordinates (because of `row-1`). So there's only condition at play here, and it will always increment by 1 `sum` which means it'll add a new red pixel.
3. So you have now your first red line.
4. For the first column, starting from the second line : conditions 1 & 2 are using invalid coordinates. Condition 3 will always return `sum = 1` which means a new red pixel. And you have your red line from top to bottom
5. And then from `row = 1` and `col = 1`, all neighbors are red, which leads to a new white pixel. Unfortunately, white does contain some red, so it'll always be the sames conditions that are met, and you have your white background.

I haven't been able to find the complete algorithm for this method to build a Sierpinski carpet, so I can't really correct it. But you should be extra careful with these edges situations : what should be the three neighbors if you are on the first line or first row ?

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! I completely overlooked that white has 255 Red! I know how to get that fixed, thanks! :D

EDIT: Upvoted ya, but not enough reputation points.

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved your problem, I think you can accept the answer (check mark under the vote options) no matter how many points you have.

Comment: Got it done! Also it does work now :) 

http://imgur.com/774651m

Always amazes me how small my problems seem after I get them corrected haha
Thanks again!